# Vector space with homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question states:

Which are the following are subspaces of M (nxn):

And the main problem I'm having trouble understanding is with this question:

The set of all n x n matrices A for which Ax=0 has only the trivial solution.

How would I go about proving if this is a subspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we know $V$ is a vector space a priori, then a space $W$ contained in $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if there is closure under scalar multiplicaton and addition.

What does it mean for a square matrix $A$ such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ to have only the trivial solution?

This means that $A$ is invertible.

Can you find two invertible matrices such that when you add them together you do not get an invertible matrix?

Yes! Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\
1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&-1\\
-1&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus $A+B=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ which is not an invertible matrix since $\det(A+B)=0$.

Since we have demonstrated that adding two matrices together in our supposed subspace yields a matrix **not** in our subspace, the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ for which $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution is not a subspace of $M_{nn}$ matrices.

Comment: Oh okay thanks so much! I just wasn't very familiar with homogeneous systems and didn't know that the trivial solution simply means that it's invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Are these matrices closed under addition?

Does the $0$ matrix belong to the set of these matrices?

If your answer is no to any of the above questions, then you do not have a subspace.

Comment: Sorry I probably should've pointed expanded my question more. I already knew what proves a subspace, I just needed to understand how to do so with a homogeneous system with the trivial solution